# Which hook to use on initial creation of a node?

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to execute a script once a new piece of content of a specific type has been created, but not updated. Which hook would I use for this?

I basically want to execute a script that will node_load the entity reference field and then email a bunch of users from that referenced node.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for [`hook_node_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7?no_cache=1439848438) where `$node` should contain your node reference field.

Comment: Also, [`hook_entity_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) for all entities, not only nodes.